# Can I create a git repository that pulls parts from multiple git repositories

Tags: git

I have multiple web applications that each have their own git repository.  Each of the repos also contains a suite of Selenium tests that I run after each build.  As there are interdependencies between the applications I usually run all of the tests every time an update is made anywhere.

Is there a way of setting up a git repo that contains only the Selenium tests for all of these applications so that when I push an update to the tests in any Application's repo the update is automatically pushed to the new Selenium Tests repo too?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) can be what you are looking for. Unfortunately, once when I used them, it was not possible to automatically download changes. This required additional scripts in crontab.